# How To Change Background Color on CheckBox in Kendo Grid Column

Tags: checkbox, kendo-ui

We have a JavaScript/Angular web app that uses many "checkbox" controls on many web page forms.

We also use the Kendo grid (k-grid) in several places with checkbox columns that display the checkmark icon in the column.  (Note these are "checkbox" and not "k-checkbox.)

Outside of the k-grid, the checkboxes show with a color background when the box is checked.

Inside the grid, the background color does not change between the checked and unchecked boxes.

Is there some way to get the background in the checkbox to be a given color when the checkbox is in the k-grid and is checked?

I tried setting the "accent-color" for the checkbox, but that didn't change anything when it is in the k-grid.

```
    input[type='checkbox']:checked {
        vertical-align: sub;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
        accent-color: #00ff00;
    }
```

This is in the .css file.  I know the code is used, because I can change the color of the checkbox border and that shows up in the k-grid.  But the accent-color does not show up.

[Browser DevTools shows accent-color is not overridden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh3SX.jpg)

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you inspect the checkbox in the browser devtools, does it show the accent-color being set/overidden by anything else?

Comment: No, the accent-color does not appear to be overridden by anything else.

Comment: I added a link in the original post showing a screenshot from DevTools that indicates that the accent-color is not overridden.

Comment: What method are you using to show the checkboxes within the k-grid?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that question, but the problem has been solved.
Thanks for your question.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by replacing the code I originally poste with this:

```
    input[type='checkbox'] {
        vertical-align: sub;
    }
    input[type='checkbox'] {
        height: 12px;
        width: 12px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        opacity: 1;
        appearance: none;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background: #fff;
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    input[type='checkbox'][disabled] {
        background-color: lightgray;
    }
    input [type='checkbox']:checked {
        border: 1px solid #FFF;
        
    }
    input[type='checkbox']:checked:before,
    input[type='checkbox']:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        height: 2px;
        background: #000;
    }
    input[type='checkbox']:checked:before {
        width: 6px;
        top: 5px;
        left: 1px;
        transform: rotate(44deg);
    }
    input[type='checkbox']:checked:after {
        width: 12px;
        top: 4px;
        left: 3px;
        transform: rotate(-55deg);
    }
    input[type='checkbox']:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
```

I don't know why this works, but it does.  It causes the checkboxes to work as they normally do without colorizing the background.